# Manage None values in F String

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, f-string

I am creating a string using f string and need to avoid fields which are None.

I am currently using below code

```
def output(self) -> str:
        data = ''
        data += 'Books: [\n'
        for bookid, firstname, lastname in zip(self.book_id, self.first_name, self.last_name):
            data += f'{{book_id: "{bookid}", first_name: "{firstname}",last_name : "{lastname}"}},\n'
        data = data [:-2] + '\n'
        data += ']\n'
        return data
```

I get below output:

> Books: [    {
> book_id: "123",
> first_name: "John",
> last_name: "None"    },
> {
> book_id: "567",
> first_name: "Merry",
> last_name: "Jones"    } ]

How to ensure that None fields should not be part of the string in the for loop. I want the output as below:

> Books: [    {
> book_id: "123",
> first_name: "John"},
> {
> book_id: "567",
> first_name: "Merry",
> last_name: "Jones"} ]

Comment: you're `'None'` is a string?

Comment: the self variable am using it as part of string formation. In the class None is not a string

Comment: Are you trying to generate JSON? If no, why not? If yes, use the `json` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below I am able to get the desired output:

```
def output(self) -> str:
        data = ''
        data += 'Books: [\n'
        for bookid, firstname, lastname in zip(self.book_id, self.first_name, self.last_name):
          data += '{'
          data += f'book_id: "{bookid}",'
          data += f'firstname: "{firstname}",'
          if last_name:
            data += f'lastname: "{lastname}"'
         data += '}'
        data = data [:-2] + '\n'
        data += ']\n'
        return data
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get the Books and omit those values which are `None`.

```
Books = [ { book_id: "123", first_name: "John", last_name: "None" } ]
```

You can have any number of elements in Books list.

```
new_Books = [{k:v for k,v in Books[x].items() if v != 'None'} for x in range(len(Books))]
```

if it is not a string then:

```
new_Books = [{k:v for k,v in Books[x].items() if v is not None} for x in range(len(Books))]
```

Another way can be to use `if` condition in the `for loop` but, I am exactly not sure how to implement it since do not have the actual data.

Comment: Edited the question since I have more than one element

Comment: Edited the answer for any number of elements in `Books` list.